# Installing nginx + geoip with puppet

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, puppet, geoip

I'm currently using:

```
mod 'nginx', :git => 'https://github.com/puphpet/puppet-nginx.git'
```

with a customised puphpet file that loads nginx but the version we get installed does support 
*–with-http_geoip_module*.

All of the posts on installing geoip functionality, suggest that the only way to get geoip support is to recompile nginx. 
Search for compiling packages with puppet suggests it's not the best way forward. Is there anywhere I can get the pre-packaged nginx module that supports geoip?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Which linux distr you use?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find a repo that has this module already added. If you find it, you can simply use that.

This one may be what you need: https://launchpad.net/~nicolas-zin/+archive/ubuntu/nginx

Answer (score 0):

Puppet workflows that rely on compiling your own packages are actually commonplace. What's *not* a good idea is for Puppet to do the actual compiling.

Build and maintain your packages with whatever tool chain fits your needs best. Maintain a package repository, and use Puppet to configure your nodes to use your repo. Puppet can then install your custom packages just like any other.